# VPN still showing my IP address

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I have 2 PCs at different locations: 1 at work & 1 at home.

The 1st PC is at home and it is a server and the 2nd PC is my work(client) PC.

At home I have setup VPN incoming connection on windows 7 and at work I am able to connect to my home VPN server via windows VPN Connections.

Problem I am facing is: When on my work PC I check my IP address via ipaddress.com, it doesn't show me IP of VPN server. How can I make it show that?

Comment: Have a read of this, it may be that, although you're using a website to check your IP (and it still gives your office IP), the request wasn't "directed" towards your VPN, so it uses your default gateway (your office connection). You should configure your VPN connection to send ALL traffic through it. http://superuser.com/questions/177052/on-windows-7-vpning-to-work-how-to-force-all-traffic-to-use-vpn

Comment: `Problem I am facing is. when on my work PC I check my ip address via ipaddress.com. it doesn't show me IP of VPN server.` - How is this a problem? Also, you probably need to configure the VPN client to use the remote gateway.

Comment: This behavior is configuired on the VPN server end.  What exactly is the question, because how you configure it, depends on specific details you didn't share.

Comment: @Ramhound: The question being asked is how to make the work PC show the VPN sever address when it's checked via something like ipaddress.com.

Comment: @BigChris Thanks I will try it when I get home(it looks like the solution I am looking for). & Thanks to Martineau for pointing out to Ramhound that question has been asked already.